# How to add custom prefix to your git commit messages using git aliases?

Tags: git, automation, alias, commit

Let's say I want to make my commits more *fancy*.
Every single commit would have a special prefix type included in "-" symbol. For example :

```
-feat- : Added new feature
-fix- : Fixed this annoying bug
-refactor- : Refactored this piece of code
-chore- : Wrote some tests
```

I want to automate all those prefixes using git aliases i. e. create custom commands for each of the type : `comfeat`, `comfix`, `comref` and `comchore`.

So far I've tried doing something like this:

```
comfeat = "!f() { git add --all && git commit -am '-feat- : ${1}'; }; f"
```

And when I try to call this command I would get this :

```
PS D:\Projects\Test> git comfeat "Added new feature"
[master 9fcb0c9] -feat- : ${1}
```

P.S. I have no prior knowledge in bash/shell so any help will be much appreciated.

P.S.S. I've seen people using git hooks for extracting branch names and prepending them to commits, but I am working alone on the project, so I don't have many branches for each feature I'm working on.

Comment: First thing you can do is try `f() { git add --all && git commit -am '-feat- : ${1}'; }; f` in [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after some digging and with the help of ChatGPT thingie I actually found a solution to this problem. My finalized version of alias part of .gitconfig file looks like this:

```
[alias]
    comfeat = !sh -c 'git add -A && git commit -m \"-feat- : $1\"' -
    comfix = !sh -c 'git add -A && git commit -m \"-fix- : $1\"' -
    comchore = !sh -c 'git add -A && git commit -m \"-chore- : $1\"' -
    comref = !sh -c 'git add -A && git commit -m \"-refactor- : $1\"' -
```

Now I can type:

```
git comref "Refactored user class."
```

and my commit message would look like:

```
[master 0ba3e4c] -refactor- : Refactored user class.
```

Comment: Where did the `[master 0ba3e4c]` part come from?